# Excel VBA reverse progress bar

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a progress bar to show the user the status of a running macro, however because the macro deletes rows it is running backwards `For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1`, meaning that my progress bar is running from 100% down to 2%.

I have only ever counted up with `i`, is it possible to make the progress read the info backwards when counting down, so to the user it visibly is counting up?

```
Sub update()
Dim lastRow As Integer, email As String, pctCompl As Single

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    email = Trim(Cells(i, 3).Value)
    Set c = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A").Find(email, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    pctCompl = i
    progress pctCompl
Next i

End Sub

Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)
UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2
DoEvents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
progress pctCompl
```

with

```
progress Abs(Round(i / lastRow * 100, 0) - 100) + 1
```

There's no need to set `i` to a variable called `pctCompl` - just pass the value to the procedure.

Comment: Ok great thanks, I did think about this but I now get "364% Completed" (or whatever the last row count is).

Comment: Good point - I hadn't thought about that.  I've updated the code to calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 2):

as an out of the box answer you may want to consider this sub:

```
Sub update()    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
            With .offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror(match(RC3,Sheet3!C1,0),"""")"
                .value = .value
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                .Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With
end Sub
```

which shouldn't require any progress bar at all...

Comment: The only requirement is due to client request, but appreciate the suggestion, will take a good look at this.